# Windows Phone Button Alignment

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, button, grid

I want to add a button based on the image to my Windows Phone Page via code. I create a grid and add the button to it.

I wrote the following:

```
 Grid grd = new Grid();
 grd.Height = 92;
 grd.Width = 271;
 grd.Margin = new Thickness(0);
 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.Name ="Name1";
 btn.Margin = new Thickness(0);
 btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
 btn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
 ImageBrush imb = new ImageBrush();
 imb.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("my_picture.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
 btn.Background = imb;
 btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.0);
 btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
 grd.Children.Add(btn);
 wrapPanel1.Children.Add(grd);
```

The problem is that still there is some space between the borders of the grid (271*92) and the button itself. The button doesn't fill the entire grid (or maybe the body of the button doesn't fill the space allocated for the button). 
How can I solve these problem and delete those unwanted margins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make a button without any border. button has a grid surround contentcontrol.

you can edit its template, set the background brush of outside grid.

Answer (score 0):

try to set Button Padding to zero .